# JSF: Wait for party, then redirect

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, redirect

I'm using JSF 2.0 and Glassfish 3.1 and have the following problem:

I've got an application in which two users must participate. The first user should set up the session and then get to a wait page. When the second user joins, the first one should be redirected to the application page. Is this possible in JSF, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create an Ajax polling mechanism
- Invoke an action from Ajax, check if condition met
- If met using JavaScript code redirect the user (Or you can also make it redirect from action)

Comment: Some third party components would make this easier for you. check out richfaces a4j:poll http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/nightly_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jpoll or primefaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pollStartStop.jsf.

Comment: @Dave definitely. a4j:poll is very useful thing